# How to display two plot in a specific position with Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

[image: Example of the result]

Hi to all,

When I run a Matlab code which generate two plot, these are overplotted (the second over the first).

I would like obtain a result as this figure, where the two plots are like in a `subplot(211)` and `subplot(212)`, the first and the second in two colons, but without using `subplot`.

It is possible?

**UPDATE**

I generate this two plot with two subfuncion:

```
function create_figure(X1, YMatrix1, p)
%CREATE_FIGURE(X1, YMATRIX1)
%  X1:  vector of x data
%  YMATRIX1:  matrix of y data
%  P: parameters used in legend

% Create figure
figure1 = figure('Name','Acceleration Power vs. Velocity LPF 1st order');
...
```

and

```
function create_figure_gamma(X1, YMatrix1, p)
%CREATE_FIGURE_GAMMA(X1, YMATRIX1, P)
%  X1:  vector of x data
%  YMATRIX1:  matrix of y data
%  P: parameters used in legend

% Create figure
figure1 = figure('Name','gamma trend vs. Velocity');
...
```

Of course, I can give in output the parameter `figure1`, writing:

```
function figure1 = create_figure(X1, YMatrix1, p)
```

I think that which this parameter is possible set the position of the two plots, but I do not know the procedure respect the generic window size.

Comment: Could you post the code where you generate your plots, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also set the Units to 'normalized' and enter relative positions for the figures:

```
set(h1,'Units','normalized');
set(h2,'Units','normalized');
set(h1,'Position',[0.1021    0.1708    0.2917    0.3500]);
set(h2,'Position',[0.4021    0.1700    0.2917    0.3508]);
```

This way you are independent of the current screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

This would produce two figures with plots side by side:

```
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);

h1=figure
plot(x,y1);
h2=figure
plot(x,y2);
% x, y, width, height
set(h1,'Position',[20 616,560,420])
set(h2,'Position',[20+560 616,560,420])
```

Comment: Not exactly, the two plots go out of the screen size (in up).

Comment: the position numbers are pixels so set them to any value you please. I have 1980x1200 and i placed the plots at upper corner.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is not exact for me, but with you I have solve the question. I use `set(figure1,'Position',[52 130 560 420])` and `set(figure1,'Position',[632 130 560 420])`.